# obtain the smallest value of a column in relation to the maximum value of another column

Tags: r, dataframe, max, min

I have a question regarding the handling of values ​​in a data.frame. 
The following data.frame would get the value of the first column that are in the same row as the maximum value of the second column. 
In case there are several equal maximum values ​​in the second column, I would like to return the smallest value of them in the first column

```
    power   total   found
1   31.0    7   7
2   30.5    8   7
3   30.0    9   8
4   29.5    9   8
5   29.0    9   7
6   28.5    8   7
7   28.0    10  8
8   27.5    10  8
9   27.0    10  8
10  26.5    11  9
11  26.0    11  9
12  25.5    9   8
13  25.0    9   9
14  24.5    8   8
15  24.0    10  9
16  23.5    8   7
17  23.0    9   8
18  22.5    7   7
19  22.0    7   7
20  21.5    7   7
21  21.0    4   4
22  20.5    4   4
23  20.0    3   3
24  19.5    2   2
25  19.0    2   2
26  18.5    2   2
27  18.0    2   2
28  17.5    1   1
29  17.0    1   1
30  16.5    0   0
31  16.0    0   0
32  15.5    0   0
33  15.0    0   0
```

Comment: This is a fairly straightforward exercise in R.  Can you share what you've tried so far an why it hasn't worked?

Comment: `min(dat[dat[,2] == max(dat[,2]),1])`

Comment: Thank you very much to all, I had never worked with maxima and minima in R so I did not know how to work with them, I have helped a lot.

Comment: I used the following code, but these data certainly do not know how to continue to get what they wanted. 
max_total <-max (DF_N_EPC_AND_FOUND_EPC [2]) 
positions <-which (DF_N_EPC_AND_FOUND_EPC [2] == max_total)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Create some fake data
set.seed(14)
df = data.frame(power = sample(seq(15,31,0.5),30, replace=TRUE), 
     total= sample(c(0,1,2,3,7:11), 30, replace=TRUE), 
     found=sample(c(0:2,7:9), 30, replace=TRUE))

df$total[c(5,9)] = NA  # Add some missing data

# Minimum of `power` at maximum of `total`
min(df$power[df$total==max(df$total, na.rm=TRUE)], na.rm=TRUE)
[1] 17.5
```

If you want to see all the values of `power` at the maximum value of total:

```
df$power[df$total==max(df$total, na.rm=TRUE)]
[1]   NA   NA 17.5 25.0 30.5 31.0
```

You can use the `which` function if you don't want missing values returned:

```
df$power[which(df$total==max(df$total, na.rm=TRUE))]
[1] 17.5 25.0 30.5 31.0
```

`which` returns only the row indices for which the logical test is `TRUE`, while the logical test alone returns a value of `TRUE`, `FALSE`, or `NA` for every single row.